# iFrame jQuery - Parent scroll to top of iFrame while loading new iFrame content

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll

This is my script loaded in an iFrame that is loaded into a parent page.

**QUESTION:** 
I want it to scroll to the top of the iframe each time they click on specified 
content in the iFrame and at the same time have the contents of the iFrame change pages.

(Example I click a submit button in the iFrame to load new content in iFrame. At the same time parent page scrolls to the top of the iFrame)

I have given the iFrame an id of 'iFrame'.  When I click on the element in the iFrame called 'imageField' it will submit a form and load new content in the iframe. But I also want it to scroll to the top of the iFame on in the main page the iframe is loaded on.

The reason is because some content is bigger and when they hit submit from the larger content in the iFrame and it goes to smaller content it looks as tho the screen is blank because they had to scroll done the main page to see the content. So I want to main page hosting the iFrame to scroll to the top of the iFrame as the new iFrame content is loading.

**Here is the code in the iFrame:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $("#imageField").click(function (){

                $('html, body').animate(
                    {
                    scrollTop: $("#iFrame").offset().top
                     }, 2000);

        });
    });
</script>
```

**My iFrame Code:**

```
<iframe src="questions/questions.php" name="inlineframe" width="550"
marginwidth="5"  height="1500" marginheight="5" scrolling="auto" 
frameborder="0" id="iFrame" ></iframe>
```

Comment: if you are using an <a> tag to load the new iframe content, then you could try using href="#" to scroll to the top of the page, or #iFrame, to scroll to the top of the iFrame, and use onclick event to fire your script..

Comment: I am close I think. The jQuery is able to control the iFrame and other div content but not the scrolling of the main page. What did you mean with your suggestion?

Comment: I think I found a work around. Now I just need to know how to call a jQuery function on the main page from jQuery in an iframe.

Comment: well using href="#" will scroll your iframe to the top, but after re-reading your question, you want the window to scroll to the top of the iframe. This article may be of use,, http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/index.html?page=7#multwinfram

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On the main page, place a javascript function:

```
// This is main page
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function scrollFrame(position) {
        position += $('#myFrameID').offset().top;
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: position }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

On the child page inside iframe, change the javascript to

```
    $("#imageField").click(function () {
        if (window != window.top) // the page is inside iframe
            window.top.scrollFrame(0); // change the position if any. 0 is top
    });
```